# How can I create a docker image then upload it to my repositary?

Tags: go, docker

the docker image i need to create must be able to run a GO app with the link given below
https://github.com/raikikon/cloud-torrent
i want this GO app to be included in docker image ..

i followed this but it doesn't seems to working
https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/

Comment: Which part is not working? What did you do? Please elaborate more on your question so that we can figure out the problem in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That app already has a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/raikikon/cloud-torrent/blob/master/Dockerfile) and an [image on the public Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jpillora/cloud-torrent/), so unless you want to modify it you don't need to build an image at all. As the README says, just:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v /path/to/my/downloads:/downloads jpillora/cloud-torrent
```

If you do want to build your own version, clone the repo and make your changes, then build it using the Dockerfile in the repo:

```
docker build -t my-cloud-torrent .
```

If you are running your own registry and don't want to use the public Hub, you can tag your own image and push it to your registry (assuming you are running the registry on the local box at default port 5000):

```
docker tag my-cloud-torrent localhost:5000/my-cloud-torrent
docker push localhost:5000/my-cloud-torrent
```